# Can't load curl.so lib (entware)

Tags: php, linux, lighttpd

I get this error in php error log on lighttpd startup:

> *PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl.so' (tried:
>   /opt/lib/php/curl.so (/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: internal error)*

As far as I understand it - curl.so tries to link libcrypto, looks at what I have in default directory and fails for some reason. But I'm not certain that that's even the problem.

I tried changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH /etc/ld.so.conf to look at a different path first. Perhaps at /opt/lib, since it has some entware libs, such as libssl.so.1.0 to no effect.
I also tried updating php, reinstalling php7-mod-openssl and everything php-related.

Comment: *`/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: internal error`* looks ominous. It may be saying OpenSSL 1.1 caused an internal error. It may need OpenSSL 1.0.2, which is *not* binary compatible with OpenSSL 1.1. What does `ldd` say about the libraries?

Comment: It actually wanted that 1.1 version, but NOT the one I had in my /usr/lib already, but another one that comes with entware, apparently. I managed to fix it with <i>opkg upgrade</i> - which I didn't want to do really, since everything was working just fine except curl. Some upgrade scripts removed /opt/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 and libssl.so.1.0.0 and replaced them with 1.1 versions.

Answer (score 0):

It fixed itself with the upgrade of all entware packages *opkg upgrade*.

It seems to me that I installed the latest version of mod-curl, which wanted me to have entware-specific libcrypto/libssl v1.1 in entware location (/opt/lib/ in my case), and not what I had in /usr/lib, and also not version 1.0.0 which I had in my /opt/lib/.

Another solution would be to install an older version of php7-mod-curl, but I have no idea which one works with that older libcrypto.so.1.0.0. So, if anyone else has a similar issue I suggest backing up and upgrading.